# Asp.Net MVC project with n-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I want to asp.net mvc project using n-tier architecture. I have Confused in that issue;

I have 4 tiers that are ***BLL***, ***DAL***,***Entities*** and ***WebUI***. ***WebUI*** tier is a asp.net mvc project. I added data model into ***entities*** tier. In ***DAL***, I create some classes about crud opparations using entity framework. Finally I serve this classes as repositories on ***BLL***. ***BLL*** knows ***DAL*** and ***entities*** tiers, ***DAL*** knows ***entites*** tier and ***WebUI*** is **only** knows ***BLL***. In *WebUI*, I can access repositories where is into ***BLL***. 
But this repositories' return values are entity classes. I have to give a reference from ***entities*** to ***WebUI*** tier. I don't want that ***WebUI*** accesses databese **directly**. It should access database using repositories inside ***BLL***.

What should I do? I want to do right thing. Is anything wrong my
architecture?

Thanks for helping answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have another project that has only models for BLLEntities.

BLL will always have to map BLLEntities to DALEntities and DALEntities to BLLEnttiies.

You can use AutoMapper for that.

Any Layer above BLL should deal with BLL entities and not with DALEntities.